# I am trying to implement flames game in python.Not able to remove all matching character?

Tags: python

```
def flames(l,l1):
    for i in l:
        if i in l1:
            l.remove(str(i))
            l1.remove(str(i))
n1=input("Enter first name:")
n2=input("Enter Second name:")
l=list(n1)
l1=list(n2)
flames(l,l1)
print(l)
print(l1)
```

I didn't completed my code entirely.But i am done with removing matched character.But the problem is its removing only first matched character.It's not removing remaining match characters.What is the problem in my code?

Comment: As currently stated, this post states a bunch of facts, and identifies one of them as a problem, but does not ask a question. You'll get more and better attention if you ask a question, preferably one that identifies the part you're having the most trouble understanding.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy "both the loops"? There is only one loop. (I think there being only one loop is itself one of many problems with this code given its apparent intent, another being the in-place mutation of a collection during iteration, but this question needs some heavy editing to make it answerable.)

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use a `dict` instead of a `list` to keep track of the letters left in each name. For instance, if the name is "Billy", the `dict` would be: `{"b":1, "i":1, "l":2, "y":1}`. In this way you can easily remove all instances of the letter because they're all stored in the same location.

Easiest way to create the dictionaries for each name would be dictionary comprehension:

```
n1 = input("Enter first name: ").lower()
d1 = { char:n1.count(char) for char in n1 }
```

Of course, the order of these letters doesn't matter and will likely appear in a different order. Also notice that the "B" in "Billy" becomes "b" in the dictionary. This might be a matter of preference for purposes of this game, but generally you would want to convert all characters to lowercase so upper and lower case letters are not treated as distinct.

There's one more thing to consider when using a `dict` rather than a `list` to store the characters: you can't modify the dictionary as you're iterating over it, you'll get a `RuntimeError`. So as you're iterating through `d1` (the characters in the first name) and deleting the matching characters in `d2`, you'll have to remember the matched characters so you can delete them from `d1` later.

```
d1ToDel = []
for k in d1:
    if k in d2:
        del d2[k]
        d1ToDel.append(k)
for k in d1ToDel:
    del d1[k]
```

After that, you just have to sum up the values remaining in each dictionary, which will give you the remaining number of characters after removing all matches. And then do a little modulo arithmetic to figure out which of the "Flames" characters the pair will land on.

Comment: Assuming you're asking about why it is only removing the first element found.. it's because that is what the list.remove() method does. You'll have to loop through each character of the second name to see if it matches and remove each separately.